# MKTileOverlay zoom level greater than 21

Tags: ios, zooming, mapkit, mktileoverlay

Since iOS 7, we are able to set custom overlays for maps in a very simple way. I'm using my own tile overlays, with zoom greater than 21. MKTileOverlay Class, has a property "maximumZ", but according to the documentation:

> The default value of this property is 21. Setting the value of this property to a number greater than the default does not guarantee the use of those extra zoom levels.

Is there any other option which could guarantee me extra zoom levels? Maybe using google maps, or other engine?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use another framework like [Mapbox](http://mapbox.com/mapbox-ios-sdk), which should support higher zooms.

Comment: Mapbox has it's own downsides, for example it looks, i can't set custom heading... It's impossible there is no way to achieve zoom levels greater than 21 on MapKit... Thanks for response anyway.